# SWIFT - call function at specific time of day

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to make an app and at 9am I want to call a function and send an a notification. Then another at 12pm, and another at 6pm. Everyday. Does anyone know the best way how?

Comment: If you app won't be in the foreground at those times then you will need to schedule local notifications.

Comment: Yes, you have to use Local Notifications

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1

Comment: @IBAction your link goes to a retired document. Here's the current version of local notifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: @JeremyP thanks, my fault

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) :

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 9
dateComponents.minute = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, 
                                            repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, 
                                    content: YourContent, 
                                    trigger: trigger)
```